# Calculating mean values based on numpy array mask, getting the mean of all values at the location in the mask, and a mean of the other values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've built a mask to point at certain locations in my dataframe. I want to be able to calculate the the mean of all values at the locations in the mask, and then the mean of all values outside of the mask. Here is my current code:

```
mask_number = 5
no_overload_cycles = 2
hyst = pd.DataFrame({"test":[12, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 10, 9, 7, 5, 3, 6, 3, 2 ,1, 5, 2]})

list_test = []
for i in range(0,len(hyst)-1,mask_number):
    for x in range(no_overload_cycles):
        list_test.append(i+x)
    
mask = np.array(list_test)

print(mask)

[0 1 5 6 10 11 15 16]

overload_mean = (hyst.loc[mask,'test']).mean() 
baseline_mean = (hyst.loc[~mask,'test']).mean()
```

Basically, I want `overload_mean` to be the mean of all values in `test` that are located at the mask, and `baseline_mean` to be the mean of all values that are in `test` that are not referenced by the mask. My current code gives me this error:

```
baseline_mean = (hyst.loc[~mask,'test']).mean() 

KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([    -1,     -2,     -6,     -7,    -11,    -12,    -16,           dtype='int64', length=11858)] are in the [index]"
```

I thought I could use the tilde to reference every result not in the mask? Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In addition to the answer below, if you had used a boolean mask (same size as the array) instead of indices, you method would have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mask` is an array of integers, so `~mask` is essentially `-mask` and you can't do `.loc[-mask]` because these negative numbers are not in the index. You want:

```
overload = hyst.iloc[mask]

overload_mean = overload['test'].mean()
baseline_mean = hyst.drop(overload.index)['test'].mean()

print(overload_mean, baseline_mean)
```

Output:

```
4.5 4.818181818181818
```

**Note** if your data is range index, you can do:

```
overload_mean = hyst.loc[mask, 'test'].mean()
baseline_mean = hyst.drop(mask)['test'].mean()
```

**Note 2**: Or, you can convert `mask` into a boolean array, and your code would work:

```
mask = np.isin(hyst.index, list_test)

overload_mean = (hyst.loc[mask,'test']).mean() 
baseline_mean = (hyst.loc[~mask,'test']).mean()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect. I guess my understanding wasn't quite right, but cheers for the help.